# How can I add '@' alias to vitest config file?

Tags: typescript, vitest

I have a test file with this import:
`import { useGlobalStore } from "@stores"`

The path is `src/stores`

That works correctly within the project, but when testing, I get this error:
`Error: Failed to resolve import "@stores" from "src/components/Footer/__test__/Footer.test.tsx". Does the file exist?`

Previously using Jest, I fixed it using moduleNameMapper:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^stores/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/stores/$1",
  },
```

I tried to add it in Vitest config according to the documentation, but I got no results.
This is my config file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    resolve: {
      // ...rest of the code ...
      alias: {
        // I tried all the commented lines without success

        // '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        // '@': './src',
        // '@stores': './src/stores', 
        // '@/stores': new URL('./src/stores', import.meta.url).pathname, 

        '@/': new URL('./src/', import.meta.url).pathname, 
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I tried most things with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vitest documentation explains, if the project relies on `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json` Vite doesn't consider `tsconfig.json` by default.

The most practical solution is to install `vite-tsconfig-paths` and modify `vitest.config.js` as follows:

```
// install and import tsconfigPaths
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig({

  //add tsconfigPaths() below
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],

  test: {
    // rest of the code
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `fileURLToPath` (`import { URL, fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';`):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.mjs', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
  },
```

In addition, you need to update your typescript compiler options :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I got the same results

Comment: Answer updated, you also need to update your typescript compiler options